# CSS: un-wanted space/gap between relative divs?

Tags: css

I have two divs that are both 100% width.

I need these 2 divs to sit underneath eachother without any space or gap between them.

But there is currently a gap/space between them and I can't get rid of it.

well I can by giving `font-size:0;` to their parents but this solution doesn't work in some browsers and specifically in iOS it doesn't work at all and there is still a gap between them.!

This is a working fiddle to explain the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/densor07/

and this is my entire code:

```
<div align="center" class="casFeed" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:0; left:0; overflow:scroll;background-color:#fff;">

            <div style="position:relative;width:100%; overflow:hidden; position:relative; height:auto;">

            <img src="http://www.longrunexploration.com/upload/main_banner/2/05/banner.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: auto;"/>

            <div style="width:auto; padding:5px;min-height:15px; text-align:center;background-color:grey; position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0; color:#fff; font-size:12px;">Credits</div>
            </div>

            <div style="position:relative;width:100%; padding:5px;min-height:15px; text-align:left;background-color:blue;color:#fff; font-size:12px;margin:0;" contenteditable="false">Caption</div>

</div>
```

Could someone please advice on this issue?

**EDIT:**

**This is the gap i am referring to:**

[image]

Comment: I don't see any gap neither in Firefox nor in Chrome.

Comment: @Dez, added a screenshot. I see it in FF, CHROME and an iPhone device.

Comment: @DavidHope See my answer . Hope it helps. Mark as correct if it helps.

Comment: @YashYadav, thank you very much.

Comment: @DavidHope Welcome dear. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ***image is problem***.

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div align="center" class="casFeed" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:0; left:0; overflow:scroll;background-color:#fff;">

   <div style="position:relative;width:100%; overflow:hidden; position:relative; height:auto;">
      
   <img src="http://www.longrunexploration.com/upload/main_banner/2/05/banner.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: auto;"/>
   
   <div style="width:auto; padding:5px;min-height:15px; text-align:center;background-color:grey; position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0; color:#fff; font-size:12px;">Credits</div>
   </div>
      
   <div style="position:relative;width:100%; padding:5px;min-height:15px; text-align:left;background-color:blue;color:#fff; font-size:12px;margin:0;" contenteditable="false">Caption</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

on the img container div

```
line-height: 0;
```